# Multiple LaTeX bibliographies each in descending chronological order with reverse numbering

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

I'm working on my CV in moderncv latex document, and my plan is to have separate lists for

1. publications (type=article),
2. data sets (type=misc), and
3. presentations (type=inproceedings)

I'm looking for someone wiser to tell me, if it is indeed possible to have

- three bibliographies in a single document,
- each of them in descending chronological order (newest first), and
- with reverse numbering?

i.e.

Section: Publications

```
[9.] Publication (newest)
[8.] Publication (second newest)
...
[1.] Publication (oldest)
```

Section: Data sets

```
[5.] Data set (newest)
[4.] Data set (second newest)
...
[1.] Data set (oldest)
```

Section: Presentations

```
[11.] Presentation (newest)
[10.] Presentation (second newest)
...
[1.] Presentation (oldest)
```

So far I have managed to make one single bibliography in descending chronological order with reverse numbering for my publications (thanks internet!). If I add other entries in the same bib file and separate them by keyword or type, the numbering of the separate lists is screwed up. In that case all entries are first put in descending chronological order and assigned numbers, but only then split into separate lists. Therefore the numbering in each list is not consecutive anymore.

Here's what I used in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=ydnt,url=false,doi=true,maxnames=120]{biblatex}

% Count total number of entries in each refsection
\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1}}

% Print the labelnumber as the total number of entries in the
% current refsection, minus the actual labelnumber, plus one
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

In the main document itself, I use

```
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading[title={Publications}]
\printbibliography[title={Peer-reviewed},heading=subbibliography, type=article]
\printbibliography[title={Data},heading=subbibliography, type=misc]

\section{Presentations}
\printbibliography[heading=none, type=inproceedings]
```

Stack Overflow, I'm counting on you!

Comment: Can you combine your code blocks into one [mre] which we can compile?

Comment: Late in the game, but in case you're still looking for an answer, you might be missing a 
 few `\begin{refsection}` in your document.
Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21401/biblatex-reverse-numbering-i-e-count-down